# Delete files with certain name in all subdirectories

Tags: r

I would like to remove files with a certain name from all subdirectories. For example, my working directory is as follows: "main directory/weather_data --> weather data contains the subdirectories D0 and D1. In these subdirectories there are files with the names "rainy weather_D0.txt" and sunny weather_D0.txt". from both subdirectories (D0 and D1) I would like to remove the file with the name "rainy weather.txt"

I have tried to do it like this in R

```
pathway = "./weather_data"

do.call(file.remove, list(list.files(pathway, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "rainy weather$")))
```

Unfortunately, it does not remove the files from these subdirectories.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file.remove` directly on vector of files.

Using the pattern `'rainy weather.*\\.txt'` you can select all the files that have 'rainy weather' in their name and end with '.txt'. `recursive = TRUE` is needed to make it work in subdirectories and `full.names = TRUE` will give the complete path of the filenames to be deleted.

```
file.remove(list.files(pathway, pattern = 'rainy weather.*\\.txt$', 
            recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your text files are in subdirectories of `weather_data` you need to add the `recursive = TRUE` argument to `list.files()` - otherwise it will only find `"D0"` and `"D1"`. The `pattern` also will not find the files because `$` means end of line, so it will only find files that *end* with `"rainy weather"` (and your files *begin* with it). I suggest changing `pattern` to just `"rainy weather"`.